PyDrive2 : Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
I'm trying to use PyDrive-2 to directly store some sensor data.
I signed up google cloud API, created google drive API then I also created a OAuth 2.0 client IDs then I downloaded the JSON file and then ran the below code; upon doing that I got
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

error.
from pydrive2.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive2.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

I made sure that Authorized redirect URIs are same in my JSON file and the console.cloud.google.com but still I keep getting this error I don't know where I am going wrong.
I am also attaching my google console screenshot for your reference.
Google console screenshot
I have tried clearing my browser cache aswell
